# Error while plotting f(x) in python when x is an array of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I am just starting to try and learn python. I am having trouble plotting functions. I follow examples from the web and it seems to work fine. However, when I try it on my own stuff I get an error that the function can only take length 1 arrays to be used as scalars but I don't see the difference in my own attempts then copying plot examples. My code is as follows:

```
i = np.arange(-16, -7, 1)
r = []
y = []
for x in i:
    r.append(math.pow(10, x))

x = np.asarray(r)
y = (math.cos(1.2) - (1 / x) * (math.sin(1.2 + x) - math.sin(1.2)))
plot(x,y)
show()
```

Basically I just want to output `y=f(x)` for the values `10^-16, 10^-15...10^-7`. But I swear all the plotting examples I find implement it in the same fashion. For example, this works just fine:

```
x = arange(0, 2, 0.01)
y = 2 * sin(2 * pi * (x - 1 / 4))
plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Where are `plot` and `show` coming from? I assume `np` is numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the functions in the correct module? Python's built-in `math.cos` only takes a single scalar value, whereas `numpy.cos` takes arrays as well:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import math
>>> math.cos([1, 2, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
>>> numpy.cos([1, 2, 3])
array([ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're mixing two types of mathematical operations

- operations from the [`math`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html) module.
- operations from [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org), that work on `ndarrays` (NumPy arrays). It's more or less conventional to `import numpy as np`.

Functions from the `math` module work on float **scalars** only. If you want to use a `math` function on a set of scalars (a list, an array...), you have to apply it on every single item of your set by iteration. That's what you're currently doing when constructing your `r` list: your loop can be transformed as `r = [math.pow(10,x) for x in i]`

NumPy, on the contrary, is designed for handling large data arrays. Operations on an array are performed directly at the C level, which is far faster and more efficient than the iteratve method I described. When using `np` functions, the input set is transformed as a `ndarray` below the hood.

For example, you can create a `r` array very efficiently, using the `np.power` function:

```
r = np.power(10., i)
```

(Note that I'm using `10.` and not `10` to force the output array to have a float `dtype`. I could have done `np.power(10, i, dtype=float)` as well).

Your `y` becomes:

```
y = (math.cos(1.2) - (1. / r) * (np.sin(1.2 + r) - math.sin(1.2)))
```

It's OK to keep `math` to compute the sine and cosine of `1.2`, as it's only a scalar. But for the `sin(1.2 + x)` part, as `x` is *already* a `ndarray`, you should use `np.sin`. An alternative would be to iterate of `x` and create an array like `np.array([math.sin(i+1.2) for i in x])`, but it completely defeats the point of using `ndarrays` in the first place.

In the last example you mentioned, a step is missing:

```
from numpy import sin
```

You now have to remember that `sin` is the NumPy function, not its `math` counterpart. Because of the risk of confusion, you should probably not import functions independently and use `np.sin` instead.